# Por que não ocorre a leitura da matriz de strings?

Tags: c, c++, array

Estou criando um código que por enquanto precisa ler o nome de N empresas (cujo N é dado). Estou tentando inserir os nomes mas o programa simplesmente não lê e é a primeira vez que tento alocação dinâmica de matrizes. O código está aqui:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void LeiaDadosDasEmpresas( int quantEmpresas , char ** nomeEmpresas ){

    int i ;

    for( i = 0 ; i < quantEmpresas ; i++ ){

        printf("\nDigite o nome da %dª empresa : ", i + 1 );

        scanf("%[^\n]s", *(nomeEmpresas + i) );

    }

}


int main()
{

    int quantEmpresas, i ;
    char ** nomeEmpresas ;

    printf("Digite o numero de empresas que queira analisar : ");
    scanf("%d", &quantEmpresas );

    nomeEmpresas = (char **) malloc( quantEmpresas*sizeof(char *) );

    for( i = 0 ; i < quantEmpresas ; i++ ){

        *(nomeEmpresas + i) = (char *) malloc( 20*sizeof(char) ); /** cada nome possui no max 20 caracteres ( incluindo '/0 ' ) **/

    }

    LeiaDadosDasEmpresas( quantEmpresas , nomeEmpresas );

    return 0 ;

}
```

Comment: "`malloc( 20*sizeof(char) ); /** cada nome possui no max 20 caracteres **/`" para 20 caracteres no nome, precisas de reservar espaço para 21 bytes. E ainda ... C/C++ não existe. Em C++ é aconselhado o use de `new`, `delete`, etc; em C o use de `malloc()`, `free()`, etc é usual.

Comment: Sim. Se for isso beleza , mas já fiz inumeros códigos em c++ usando malloc() e free() e nunca deram problema.

Comment: @AlexandreSantiagodaSilva eu fui várias vezes para SP em nunca sofri nenhum acidente até hoje.

Comment: @AlexandreSantiagodaSilva 
Alguma das respostas resolveu o problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você estaria ajudando a comunidade identificando a melhor solução. Só pode aceitar uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer coisa no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

Pode ter mais algum problema mas o padrão de leitura está causando o problema. Tem alguma razão para usá-lo? Aproveitei e dei uma organizada no código e consertar outros pequenos problemas:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void LeiaDadosDasEmpresas(int quantEmpresas, char ** nomeEmpresas) {
    for (int i = 0; i < quantEmpresas; i++) {
        printf("\nDigite o nome da %dª empresa: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%s", nomeEmpresas[i]); // <=========================== mudei aqui
    }
}
int main() {
    int quantEmpresas;
    char ** nomeEmpresas;
    printf("Digite o numero de empresas que queira analisar: ");
    scanf("%d", &quantEmpresas);
    nomeEmpresas = malloc(quantEmpresas * sizeof(char *));
    for (int i = 0; i < quantEmpresas; i++) nomeEmpresas[i] = malloc(21);
    LeiaDadosDasEmpresas(quantEmpresas, nomeEmpresas);
    for (int i = 0; i < quantEmpresas; i++) printf("\nNome da %dª empresa: %s", i + 1, nomeEmpresas[i]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/TF1tLr). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vbhtrkee-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/ReadArray.c).

Não usei o `free()` porque é um exemplo descartável, em um código real eu teria feito a liberação de memória. Também não me importei com estouro de *buffer*, em código real isto é um perigo.

Em tese este [código do `scanf()` deve funcionar para aceitar espaços](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1247989/221800). Não consegui reproduzir no **ideone**, pode ser uma limitação dele:

```
scanf("%21[^\n]", nomeEmpresas[i]);
```

Mas na pergunta do SO também tem a sua sintaxe e não funciona. Não posso garantir. Se Nada disse der certo, é melhor usar o [`fgets()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets). Infelizmente eu não sei dizer porque o padrão de leitura não funciona, posso até dar uma pesquisada depois.

[Achei uma solução](http://ideone.com/1qLBCV) que não gostei muito mas resolveu. Só gostaria se eu tivesse certeza de que ela está certa, o que não é o caso.

```
scanf("%[^\n]%*c", nomeEmpresas[i]);
```

Ainda prefiro a [solução com `fgets()`](http://ideone.com/2KxtDQ) que é mais segura.

Comment: Muito obg. Mas *( p + i ) é equivalente a p[i] e malloc(21*sizeof(char)) equivalente a malloc(21) ( que no caso coloquei 20 ). Mas falta fazer o cast em malloc no seu exemplo ai.

Comment: Só coloquei (char ** ) e (char* ) na primeira e segunda alocação no seu exemplo e deu certo. Valeu ai.

Comment: Não, pelo contrário, no seu código é que está sobrando essas coisas. EU tirei conscientemente. Especificamente o `cast` é melhor não fazer. Não é só redundância. http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/221800 http://stackoverflow.com/q/1565496/221800 Talvez você esteja usando o compilador do C++. Mas este código não é C++. Escolha o que vai fazer, se vai programar em C, use o compilador do C, se vai usar o compilador do C++, programe em C++. O fato da sintaxe ser quase intercambiável, não quer dizer que deva fazer. Funcionar é diferente de ser certo.

Comment: Mas ainda tem um problema. E necessário a leitura do espaço pela função scanf

Comment: Mas sem o cast deu problema no momento do debug. O problemas foram " invalid conversion from void* to char**" e  " invalid conversion from void* to char*".

Comment: Bom. Não tenho conhecimentos aprofundado de compiladores mais , pelo que eu sei , funções da linguagem c podem ser usadas sem problema em codigos em c++.

Comment: Isto não é bem verdade. Alguma coisa pode, não tudo. E vou repetir, o fato de poder não quer dizer que deva fazer. Escute o que estou lhe dizendo: escolha programar em C ou C++, não misture os dois estilos. Isto não vai te levar a um bom lugar. Eu melhorei a resposta, não sei se resolve totalmente, não tenho como testar de um jeito melhor, só posso tentar ver depois o que pode ser, mas dei alternativas.

Comment: Sim. Entendi o seu ponto completamente , sei que deve-se levar em consideração em projetos de desenvolvimento mais aprofundado , mas isso é só um simples trabalhinho de universidade . O que estou querendo dizer é que o fato de usar malloc() não é a causa do problema do código. Mas valeu pela ajuda.

Comment: Se encontrar algo depois manda aqui fazendo o favor.

Answer (score 0):

A instrução

```
scanf("%[^\n]s", *(nomeEmpresas + i) );
//          ^^^ s a mais
```

pretende ler uma string seguida de um `s`. Como o `s` faz parte da string, o *scan* nunca acaba. Tira de lá o `s`

```
scanf("%[^\n]", *(nomeEmpresas + i) );
//          ^^ sem s
```

Comment: Sim , parece que o problema está no identificador da função scanf. Se eu utilizar scanf("%s", *(nomeEmpresas + i) ); , o programa lê normalmente , mas o mesmo não ocorre quando utilizo scanf("%[^\n]s", *(nomeEmpresas + i) ); ou até mesmo scanf("%[^\n]", *(nomeEmpresas + i) ); como me havia dito

Comment: O problema é que eu preciso ler com espaços e utilizar "%[^\n]s" seria uma opção para mim. Mas não entendo o problema.