# Programa nao executa sem ler o conteúdo da variável

Tags: c

Estou criando um programa simples para um trabalho da faculdade, que lê 2 numeros, um operador aritmetico e devolve o resultado dessa operação. Mas acontece que após printar na tela "digite o operador", o programa nao espera que eu entre com o caracter, mas finaliza logo o programa. Qual o erro? segue o código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    float n1,n2;
    char op;

    printf("Digite o primeiro operando: \n");
    scanf("%f", &n1);

    printf("Digite o segundo operando: \n");
    scanf("%f", &n2);

    printf("Digite um dos operadores aritmeticos (+,-,* ou /): \n");
    scanf("%c", &op);

    if (op == '+')
      printf("%f, %c",n1,op,n2,"=",n1+n2);
    else if (op == '-')
       printf("%f, %c",n1,op,n2,"=",n1-n2);
    else if (op == '*')
        printf("%f, %c",n1,op,n2,"=",n1*n2);
    else if (op == '/') {
        while (n2=0) {
            printf("Digite o divisor não nulo: \n");
            scanf("%f", &n2);
        }
        printf("%f, %c",n1,op,n2,"=",n1/n2);
    }
    else
        printf("Operador invalido! \n");

    return 0;             
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cauã, o que eu fiz para resolver seu problema, foi colocar um espaço em branco antes do `%c`

```
printf("Digite um dos operadores aritmeticos (+,-,* ou /):\n");
scanf(" %c", &op);
```

Para você não precisar usar o espaço em branco, você pode usar o [`fflush`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/)

```
fflush(stdin);      
printf("Digite um dos operadores aritmeticos (+,-,* ou /):\n"); 
scanf("%c", &op);
```

Comment: valeu. resolveu aqui tambem

Comment: Isso resolve meio que por coincidência, isto não é padrão em tem compilador que não funciona. http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html

Comment: Sim, eu li um pouco por cima e tenho encontrado artigos não recomendando o uso do `scanf`. Mas para uma solução até que funcionou o que propus, @bigown você poderia responder com a melhor solução para esse caso.

Comment: Já tem uma resposta sobre isto em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42981/101. Já fiz um exemplo com a solução: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/107226/101. Tem mais informações em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/87973/101. E também: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9427/101. Se pesquisar aqui no SOpt tem várias outras respostas sobre isto.

Comment: Valeu, vou dar uma lida.